# How to create a function for translate using vba CATIA?

Tags: vba, vbscript, catia

Im working on vba CATIA and I am trying to create a function for translate operation. But I am getting an error in assigning the Output of the function to an object.

Looking Forward for a solution.

Thanks in advance!!

```
Function CreateTranslate(source As Object, value As Double, direction As Double)

Set partDocument1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
Set part1 = partDocument1.Part

If direction = 1 Then
        Set hybridShapeFactory1 = part1.HybridShapeFactory
        Set hybridShapeDirection1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewDirectionByCoord(1#, 0#, 0#)

Else
    If direction = 2 Then
            Set hybridShapeFactory1 = part1.HybridShapeFactory
            Set hybridShapeDirection1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewDirectionByCoord(0#, 1#, 0#)
        Else
            If direction = 3 Then
                Set hybridShapeFactory1 = part1.HybridShapeFactory
                Set hybridShapeDirection1 = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewDirectionByCoord(0#, 0#, 1#)
              End If
      End If
End If


    Set CreateTranslate = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewEmptyTranslate()

    Set reference1 = part1.CreateReferenceFromObject(source)
    CreateTranslate.ElemToTranslate = reference1

    CreateTranslate.direction = hybridShapeDirection1
    CreateTranslate.DistanceValue = value

End Function
```

Calling the function:

```
 Set result_of_translate = hybridShapeFactory1.AddNewEmptyTranslate()
 result_of_translate = CreateTranslate(Kotfl, 0, 1)
```

Comment: what is the error? be sure to use `Set` when assigning  -> `Set result_of_translate = CreateTranslate...`

Comment: Thank you WiteHat ....using   Set  worked..:)

Comment: Cheers, I often forget `Set`. Will you accept my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating a Function to return an object, you must use the `Set` statement to assign the object to a variable or property.

`Set result_of_translate = CreateTranslate(Kotfl, 0, 1)`